Private Node Network-GoEth
i am trying to install private network of three nodes on my single laptop.
i did following:

install go-eth.
used a medium article and followed instructions
when i try to connect nodes with each other, they give networking error.
i did it on Virtual Machine
now i want to try Microsoft OS to install. Any guidance in this regard is appreciated


Which version of geth are you using? What is the genesis file like? What the error you got? The official site has a guide https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/kurtosis.
